# ANDROID WEBKIT: Select elements getting focus events, but not opening!

Tags: javascript, html, android, mobile-webkit

I have a series of select elements in a form on a mobile site. These select elements are inside a scrolling pane handled through JS and CSS3 transforms, so getting a touch/click/whatever event to register on the selects was enough of a pain in the first place. However, I'm now finding, on android only, that even though the selects are getting clicked, and are getting focus- they simply refuse to open. I'm 100% sure that the selects are getting their focus event (through debug), so honestly, I am completely stumped. Without the debug, there are no other focus/blur events on the selects. It works fine on iPhone... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've been banging my head against the wall with this same issue. It seems to be isolated to Android 2.1/2.2 (and maybe 2.0?). The selects work fine in Android 1.5/1.6. I even created a simple page that just changes the select's display style from none to block and the select still doesn't open consistently. Oddly, sometimes after page refresh it might work, then after another refresh it might be broken again. As you stated, focus and click/touch events do fire from the element, so I'm at a loss as to what the issue is.

Sometimes if I zoom the page I can get the select to open, but even then the value selected isn't represented in the select element on the page.

I submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12332) to the Android dev team, but even if it's fixed in future builds the problem will still exist in 2.1/2.2.

Anyone find a workaround for this yet?

**//---- Update ------**
If you use a webkit-transition to show/hide the element, attaching the following event to the element appears to fix the select inside of it:

```
.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd",function(e){
     this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
},false);
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works, but re-writing the element to the DOM seems to help for some reason. Tested in Android 2.1/2.2 simulator, EVO4G and MyTouch.

Comment: I have this problem. I tried your solution on my Droid 2 phone running Android 2.2 and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523309/select-box-not-displaying-on-android-in-phonegap/4811477#4811477) by a.meservy. Here is the answer, copied for everyone's convenience.

In this case the problem was actually caused by jQTouch. To fix it, just comment out these 4 lines in jqtouch.css

Under "body"

```
  /*-webkit-perspective: 800;*/
  /*-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
```

Under "body > * "

```
/*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
/*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0) scale(1);*/
```